# Why isn't than of or the repetition of the cost unnecessary in the third example?

Tags: meaning-in-context, comparison

> The cost should be less than **the cost of** sending them separately.
>
> The cost should be less than **that of** sending them separately.
>
> The cost should be less than  sending them separately.

I think all these three sentences are correct, but I would like to know why is it possible to omit "that of" or the repetition of" the cost"  in the third example. I've read many things on "that of" but can't understand why is it possible to omit it in my example.

Comment: From the context, "*sending them separately*" is understood to mean "***the cost of** sending them separately*". I can't explain why this is understood, or I'd make this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All three sentences are correct, although the second sentence sounds very awkward.

You can eliminate "the cost of" because it is implied that "sending them separately" means "the cost of sending them separately" based on the context. If that implication is not understood, then there might be a miscommunication.

Therefore, the first sentence is the best to use:

> The cost should be less than the cost of sending them separately.

Comment: I don't find the second sentence awkward myself; in fact it's the most elegant option for ellipsis.